# methods to select objects in a room

Tags: javascript, screeps

Given that I have a creep in a room, is there any other method other than "Game.creeps.creep.room.find(Game.)" to get the objects in a room?

Something like .room.sources?

Because I am currently using this:

```
var creep;
var target;
creep = Game.creeps.Creep1;
if(!creep.memory.target) {
  target = creep.pos.findNearest(Game.SOURCES,{filter:function(s) { return s.energy > 0; }});
  creep.memory.target = target.id;
}
else{
  target = creep.room.find(Game.SOURCES,{filter:function(s) { return s.id == creep.memory.target; }});
}
```

And this seems like it may be a little slow because of the filter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case someone reads this and gets confused, there was a new method added since this question was asked/answered. Game.getObjectById()

In the code above, you can replace the statement in the else block with:

```
target = Game.getObjectById(creep.memory.target);
```

Comment: Yes, this is a much better method than my original one.

Answer (score 2):

`Room.find()` is the only way to iterate through room objects at the moment.

By the way, instead of checking `energy > 0` you can simply use `Game.SOURCES_ACTIVE` constant: